# How to build a cache of the DOM that does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, dom

So I tried to build a cache of the DOM:

```
var DOM = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

However, the DOM variable seems to be a dynamic reference, so that if I change an element in the DOM, the `DOM` variable changes as well.

I tried iterating through the `DOM` variable and using the `cloneNode` method to create a deep copy of each node. This works in that it does not change when I change the DOM. However, the problem is that a cloned node does not equal its original DOM node when you compare them with the `===` operator.

So to sum up, I'm looking to create a cache of the DOM that does not change but whose nodes are still equal to the original DOM nodes.

Comment: I don't think there is a tag `<*></*>`... Did you mean `document.querySelectorAll("*")`?

Comment: @Derek `"*"` for `gEBTN ` works like `"*"` for query selector, just test it :P

Comment: @Esailija - WOOT! Didn't know that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a "live" `NodeList`, which isn't what you think at all. When you access the list, the DOM is traversed (implementation may cache it) every time to get the result. This gives the illusion of the list being live.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div") === document.getElementsByTagName("div") 
//true
```

To do what you want, simply convert it to an array. `DOM = [].slice.call(DOM)`

Answer (score 1):

You seem open to a jQuery solution, so:

```
$("*")
```

will return a jQuery object containing all the elements. It will not be updated as the DOM changes.

Or if you just want elements within the `<body>` (i.e., not `<script>` or `<meta>` elements, etc., from the `<head>`) then:

```
$("body *")
```

Being a jQuery object it will of course allow you to access jQuery methods, but you can also access the DOM elements directly with array notation:

```
var DOM = $("body *");
DOM.show();              // example jQuery method call
alert(DOM.length);       // show count of elements in DOM
alert(DOM[4].value)      // example of direct access to fifth DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the following methodology:

https://gist.github.com/3841424#file-domcache-js

Or, you may replace the DOM object with a method in this implementation:

```
var myNS = {
    myEventHandler: function(event){
        this.DOM.$el.doSomething();
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
        return {
             $el: $("#matrix")
        };
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.DOM = this.cacheDOM();
    }
};
```